# Pause between each character

Tags: php, for-loop

```
$sql = 'SELECT id FROM users';

// on envoie la requête
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !');

//on declare array comme uenter code heren array et l'incrementation a zero.
$array = array();
$i = 0;
// on fait une boucle qui va faire un tour pour chaque enregistrement
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($req))
{
// on met en array chaque id en partant de 0.
$array[$i] = $data['id'];
//on incremente
$i = $i+1;
}
//nombre qui est l'id aléatoire tant désiré :-P
$nbre = $array[array_rand($array)];

$nb = $nbre.'@';
echo '<br>';
$nbre = strstr($nb,'@', true);

$decoup = wordwrap($nbre,1," ",1);

$tab_string = explode(" ", $decoup);

for($i = 0; $i <count($tab_string); $i++){

echo $tab_string[$i] . "&nbsp;"; 
if($tab_string) {
       sleep(3);
    }

}
mysql_close();
```

How to display the result numbers one after the other, pausing for three seconds?
for example if the result is B 8 T F X, there should be a pause between each character B ..... 3 seconds ... 8 ... 3 seconds ... T..etc ...

Comment: You can't do this with PHP. Use JavaScript. That's because PHP returns a HTTP response as soon as it is ready with processing the request.

Answer (score 0):

may be there u can use sleep function.

```
int sleep ( int $seconds )`
```

Comment: This will just delay the response from the server, and everything to be returned at once. You need to do client side manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_start(); 
$buffer = str_repeat(" ", 4096)."\r\n<span></span>\r\n";
for($i = 0; $i <count($tab_string); $i++){

echo $buffer.$tab_string[$i] . "&nbsp;"; 
ob_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(3);
}
ob_end_flush();
```

It's a solution